# Какое это предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

"Его избили(,) и отправили в больницу"
Простое предложение или сложносочинённое?
По сложившейся практике вроде бы считается простым с однородными главными членами (сказуемыми). Но как-то очень уж хочется запятую поставить. Подразумевается, что "били" и "отвозили" разные лица.

Правка: **"Его избили(,) и их отправили в больницу".**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мне не хочется ставить запятую. Даже если били одни люди, а отправляли другие - наличие детерминанта (общий второстепенный член  *его*)не дает нам права ставить  запятую.

А второе предложение лучше так: Его избили, потом отправили в больницу и долго лечили. Да и первое во избежание двусмысленности я бы переделала на что-то вроде  "его избили, и он попал в больницу"

Посмотрите здесь: [Понятие о синтаксической однородности и однородных членах предложения](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-029.htm)
Как раз по интересующей Вас теме: однородные сказуемые в простом предложении или сложное предложение.

Comment: >>>наличие детерминанта (общий второстепенный член его)не дает нам права ставить запятую   
Согласен. Неподумавши. Снимаю. В оригинале там не было второстепенного члена...

Вторую фразу не надо переделывать, я её искусственно соорудил ражи этого разговора.

Comment: Не знаю. как вставлять ссылку в комментарий. Добавила в ответ.

Comment: Ну вообще-то я Валгину читал неоднократно.
Иам прямого ответа нет, хотя спасибо, ещё раз убедился, что все действительно запутано.
Я наверное поспешил этот вопрос задавать. Сформулирую попозже, если сам не разберусь.

Answer (score 3):

Именно так - предложение звучит слегка неграмотно, годится только для разговроной речи.
Однородные сказуемые должны употребляться только если подразумевается, что подлежащее - один и тот же субъект.

Comment: Совершенно с Вами согласна.

Answer (score 1):

Но по смыслу тут не понятно, что били и отвозили разные люди. У меня сложилось ощущение, что это были одни и те же, и тогда предложение все-таки простое.

Comment: Насколько важен сам субъект действия? Это же не грамматическая категория в данном случае.
А если "и потом долго лечили?"

Answer (score 0):

Сложное предложение,в котором два  простых неопределённо-личных предложения. Запятая нужна.

Comment: А это,по- вашему ,не комментарий что ли? Удаляйте,мне всё равно.Если надумаете удалить мою страницу,флаг в руки.

Comment: Если вам нравится  бред,копированный из интернета,то читайте именно бред.

Comment: Да Вы просто кипяток: не всякий же вопрос заслуживает ответа. Прочтите комментарий самого автора вопроса к ответу Ларf:  «Я наверное поспешил этот вопрос задавать. Сформулирую попозже, если сам не разберусь».

Answer (score -1):

Dear behemothus,

1. Попробуйте перевести предложение "Его избили и отправили в больницу." на английский язык.
2. В результате перевода Вы должны получить приблизительно следующее предложении "He was beaten and sent to a hospital.".
3. Если в английском варианте предложения "Его избили и отправили в больницу." Вам "как-то очень уж захочется запятую поставить", тогда смело ставьте запятую в предложении "Его избили и отправили в больницу.".

Comment: Не удаляю ответ только для того, чтобы влепить вам очередной минус.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы behemothus демонстрировал свои умственные способности.

Comment: Да я как-то не особо нждаюсь в вашем разрешении. Главное, что мне есть, что демонстрировать. Чего и вам желаю.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы behemothus демонстрировал на этом сайте не только свои умственные способности.

Comment: Чем бы дитя не тешилось...

Comment: По тексту можно определить психологический возраст его автора. Судя по текстам, которые сочинил behemothus, его психологический возраст составляет от 12 до 15 лет.

Comment: От 12 до 15 - прекрасный возраст! @Галактион, чего это Вы развоевались? На "Математике" были вежливей...

Answer (score -3):

Его избили и отправили в больницу.
Никаких сравнений с английскими делать не надо. Мыслим по-русски.
Написанное по-русски (Его избили и отправили в больницу) уже ясно заявляет о себе. Два однородных сказуемых -  глаголы в третьем лице - без подлежащего. Таким образом, предложение неопределённо-личное из простых. 
Избили и отправили - глаголы подразумевают третье лицо, множественное число ( местоимение "они"). Глагольное время неважно. Примеры: Сообщают о приближении урагана; говорят о повышении цен; рассказывали по радио о новом приборе, передавали спектакль по пьесе А.Н.Островского.
Лорана, вы поняли, что на третье лицо у нас в языке указывают местоимения: "он, она, оно" (ед.число), "они" (для всех родов,множ. число)?

Comment: О каком третьем лице Вы говорите? Время прошедшее.